# 'no unique mode; found %d equally common values' % len(table) statistics.StatisticsError: no unique mode; found 2 equally common values

Tags: python-3.x

when i use large number of data show this Error:('no unique mode; found %d equally common values' % len(table) statistics.StatisticsError: no unique mode; found 2 equally common values). But use 100 number of data it's work.i can't understand what the reason it doesn't work any one help and how to solve this Error pls.

data link:https://github.com/YoeriNijs/TweetAnalyzer

code:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

import nltk, random, csv, sys

from nltk.probability import FreqDist, ELEProbDist
from nltk.classify.util import apply_features,accuracy

from nltk.corpus import names
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import nltk.classify.util
from nltk import NaiveBayesClassifier
from textblob import TextBlob

from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB,BernoulliNB


from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression,SGDClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC, LinearSVC, NuSVC

from nltk.classify import ClassifierI
from statistics import mode

class VoteClassifier(ClassifierI):
    def __init__(self, *classifiers):
        self._classifiers = classifiers


    def classify(self, features):
        votes = []
        for c in self._classifiers:
            v = c.classify(features)
            votes.append(v)
        return mode(votes)



def get_words_in_tweets(tweets):
    all_words = []
    try:
        for (words, sentiment) in tweets:
            all_words.extend(words)
        return all_words

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)



def get_word_features(wordlist):
    wordlist = FreqDist(wordlist)
    word_features = wordlist.keys()
    #print (word_features)
    return word_features


def selectTweets(row):
    tweetWords = []
    words = row[0].split()
    for i in words:
        i = i.lower()
        i = i.strip('@#\'"?,.!')
        tweetWords.append(i)
    row[0] = tweetWords

    if counter <= 120:
        trainTweets.append(row)
        #print(trainTweets)
        #print(('*')*30)

    else:
        testTweets.append(row)
        #print(testTweets)


def extract_features(document):
    document_words = set(document)
    features = {}
    for word in word_features:
      features['contains(%s)' % word] = (word in document_words)
    return features 


trainTweets = []
testTweets = []

#csvfile.csv
while True:

    # Ask for filename
    filename =  str(input("> Please enter a filename (.csv): "))

    #Check if filename ends with .csv
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):

        try:

            #Open file
            with open(filename, 'r',encoding='utf-8') as csvfile: 
                reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')

               #Print succes message
                print ("> File opened successfully!")


                counter = 0
                for row in reader:
                    selectTweets(row)
                    counter += 1

                print (counter,"> Wait a sec for the results...")

                word_features = get_word_features(get_words_in_tweets(trainTweets))      


                training_set = apply_features(extract_features, trainTweets)
                test_training_set=apply_features(extract_features, testTweets)


                classifier = nltk.classify.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)
                classifier.show_most_informative_features(5)
                print (nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier,test_training_set))


                MNB_classifier = SklearnClassifier(MultinomialNB())
                MNB_classifier.train(training_set)
                print("MultinomialNB accuracy percent:",nltk.classify.accuracy(MNB_classifier, test_training_set))

                BNB_classifier = SklearnClassifier(BernoulliNB())
                BNB_classifier.train(training_set)
                print("BernoulliNB accuracy percent:",nltk.classify.accuracy(BNB_classifier, test_training_set))




                LogisticRegression_classifier = SklearnClassifier(LogisticRegression())
                LogisticRegression_classifier.train(training_set)
                print("LogisticRegression_classifier accuracy percent:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(LogisticRegression_classifier, test_training_set))*100)



                SGDClassifier_classifier = SklearnClassifier(SGDClassifier())
                SGDClassifier_classifier.train(training_set)
                print("SGDClassifier_classifier accuracy percent:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(SGDClassifier_classifier, test_training_set))*100)

                SVC_classifier = SklearnClassifier(SVC())
                SVC_classifier.train(training_set)
                print("SVC_classifier accuracy percent:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(SVC_classifier, test_training_set))*100)

                LinearSVC_classifier = SklearnClassifier(LinearSVC())
                LinearSVC_classifier.train(training_set)
                print("LinearSVC_classifier accuracy percent:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(LinearSVC_classifier, test_training_set))*100)

                voted_classifier = VoteClassifier(classifier,
                                                  LinearSVC_classifier,
                                                  SGDClassifier_classifier,
                                                  MNB_classifier,
                                                  BNB_classifier,
                                                  LogisticRegression_classifier)
                print("voted_classifier accuracy percent:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(voted_classifier,test_training_set ))*100)



                while True:


                    tweet =  str(input("Please enter the text of the tweet you want to analize: "))
                    print (classifier.classify(extract_features(tweet.split())))



                    while True:
                        print
                        repeat =  str(input("> Do you want to check another tweet (y/n)? "))

                        if repeat == "n":
                            print ("Exit program")
                            sys.exit()
                        if repeat != "y":
                            print ("Something went wrong")
                        if repeat == "y":
                            break         

    #If file does not exist, display this"""
        except IOError:
            print ("File does not exist.")

#Else if file does not end with .csv, do this
    else:
        print ("Please open a file that ends with .csv")
```

Show this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nahid\Desktop\main folder\newcheck.py", line 163, in         <module>
    print("voted_classifier accuracy percent:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(voted_classifier,test_training_set ))*100)
  File "C:\Users\Nahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\classify\util.py", line 87, in accuracy
    results = classifier.classify_many([fs for (fs, l) in gold])
  File "C:\Users\Nahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\classify\api.py", line 77, in classify_many
    return [self.classify(fs) for fs in featuresets]
  File "C:\Users\Nahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\classify\api.py", line 77, in <listcomp>
    return [self.classify(fs) for fs in featuresets]
  File "C:\Users\Nahid\Desktop\main folder\newcheck.py", line 35, in classify
    return mode(votes)
  File "C:\Users\Nahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\statistics.py", line 507, in mode
```

'no unique mode; found %d equally common values' % len(table)
   statistics.StatisticsError: no unique mode; found 2 equally common values

Comment: There are at least two values that occur the same number of times: `mode([1, 2, 2, 3, 3])` also exhibits this behavior, as either `2` or `3` could be the mode.  How do you want to handle this case?

Comment: sir i am beginner. please sir don't angry. where need to change.please

Comment: `mode(votes)` in `VoteClassifier.classify` is failing because there is more than one mode.  You need to decide how you want to handle that case.  One way would be to use [`Counter.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) instead, which will pick one at random

Comment: thanks to you to reply sir. sir it's not work.i collect is code this link:https://pythonprogramming.net/combine-classifier-algorithms-nltk-tutorial/. i want to do this.

Comment: sir please help i follow this video tutorial:https://pythonprogramming.net/combine-classifier-algorithms-nltk-tutorial/. what i do now

Comment: sir can you help???

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this is to upgrade Python to 3.8 or higher.

In Python versions 3.7 and older there can to be only a single number that occurs the most times in the whole set. If a set contains two or more such numbers than mode becomes inconclusive and returns the exact error you got.

However, since version 3.8 the whole mathematical concept is changed. In cases in which there are two or more modes in a set, the smallest mode is selected as the result.

Example:

```
result = statistics.mode([1,1,2,2,3,3])
```

has three possible and equal solutions: **1**, **2**, or **3** as each number occurs two times in the set

in Python 3.7 this returns an error,

in Python 3.8 this returns **1** as the mode